# How to handle different templates by server groups in Chef?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

New Chef user ...

I want to push out config files for a Sumologic install. I have a basic recipe that collects logs for `/var/log/messages.` This config file (it's really a template) goes out to ALL servers. I also have a config file that should only go to let's say a web server to collect `/var/log/httpd/access.log.`

Should I be creating another recipe file (is that what you call them)? Here's what I have now.

## recipe

```
# cookbooks/ic_sumologic/recipes/config.rb
directory '/opt/SumoCollector/sources' do
  owner 'root'
  group 'sumologic_collector'
  mode '0775'
  action :create
end

# This should go to all servers
template '/opt/SumoCollector/sources/messages.json' do
  source 'messages.json.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'sumologic_collector'
  mode '0664'
  action :create
end

# This should only go to Apache servers
template '/opt/SumoCollector/sources/access_logs.json' do
  source 'access_logs.json.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'sumologic_collector'
  mode '0664'
  action :create
end
```

## template

```
# messages.json.erb 
{
    api.version:v1,
    source:{
      name:messages,
      "category":"<%= node.chef_environment %>_messages",
      automaticDateParsing:true,
      multilineProcessingEnabled:true,
      useAutolineMatching:true,
      forceTimeZone:false,
      filters:[],
      encoding:UTF-8,
      pathExpression:/var/log/messages,
      blacklist:[],
      sourceType:LocalFile
    }
}

# access_logs.json.erb
{
    api.version:v1,
    source:{
      name:messages,
      "category":"<%= node.chef_environment %>_access",
      automaticDateParsing:true,
      multilineProcessingEnabled:true,
      useAutolineMatching:true,
      forceTimeZone:false,
      filters:[],
      encoding:UTF-8,
      pathExpression:/var/log/httpd/access,
      blacklist:[],
      sourceType:LocalFile
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can make it more configurable so you don't have to declare a new template resource whenever you need a new source. What is the content of the erbs, could you make it standard with some variables that could be configured? That way you could define new sources in attributes, iterate them and have a single template declaration

Comment: Updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this for syntax errors or anything else, just did it from memory. It is also incomplete. You could make more things configurable, here I am just allowing log_source and the log source config file path to be configurable.
It could be something along this lines:

attributes

default.rb

> default['sumologic']['sources'] = nil

resources
    sumologic_source.rb

```
actions :install
    default_action :install
    attribute :source_path, :kind_of => String, :name_attribute => true
    attribute :log_source, :kind_of => String
```

providers:
    sumologic_source.rb

```
action :install do
          template new_resource.path do
            source 'sumologic.erb'
              owner 'root'
              group 'sumologic_collector'
              mode '0664'
              action :create
              variables(
                  :source => new_resource.log_source
              )
            end
        end
```

templates
default

```
sumologic.json.erb
        {
            api.version:v1,
            source:{
              name:messages,
              "category":"<%= node.chef_environment %>_access",
              automaticDateParsing:true,
              multilineProcessingEnabled:true,
              useAutolineMatching:true,
              forceTimeZone:false,
              filters:[],
              encoding:UTF-8,
              pathExpression:<%=@log_source%>,
              blacklist:[],
              sourceType:LocalFile
            }
        }
```

call in the recipe:

```
unless node['sumologic']['sources'].nil? 
  node['sumologic']['sources'].each do |source|
    sumologic source['path'] do
        action :install
        log_source source['log_source']
    end
  end
end
```

Then you could set the attribute:

```
{
   "sumologic":{
      "sources": [{"path": "/opt/SumoCollector/sources/access_logs.json", "log_source": "/var/log/httpd/access"}]
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice. So I do have one question. For the attributes, where would I be able to set it per host group? Meaning, my web servers have a different list from let's say my database servers. I think I aked my own question, in the role config.

Comment: In`resources sumologic_source.rb` ... should `:source_path` be used again, like in the recipe?

Comment: Since it is the name attribute, you are already using it in the recipe when you call the resource:
sumologic source['path'] do

Where source is one of the objects in the array attribute['sumologic']['sources']